# Mongoose findOne and save create new object and trigger uniquevalidator

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using mongo 4.4.10 (due to synology limitation)
Express, mongoose and UniqueValidator 3.0.0 (the principal suspect)

When doing this

```js
    router.get('/test',async (req,res)=>{
      try {
        const user = await UserModel.findById('abc'); //it find the user with id abc
        user.firstname = 'testOk';
        await user.save(); // <-- error and server crash         
        return res.status(200).json({message:'ok'});
      } catch (error) {
        return res.status(401).json({message:'not ok',error:error});
      }
      
    })
```

The res.status return 401 with message not ok

Error Message:

```js
    > properties: {
    >         message: 'Error, expected `_id` to be unique. Value: `6222469034b2ff0a853f7b78`',
    >         type: 'unique',
    >         validator: [Function (anonymous)],
    >         path: '_id',
    >         value: ObjectId {
    >           [Symbol(id)]: Buffer(12) [Uint8Array] [
    >              98,  34, 70, 144, 52,
    >             178, 255, 10, 133, 63,
    >             123, 120
    >           ]
    >         }
    >       },
    >       kind: 'unique',
    >       path: '_id',
    >       value: ObjectId {
    >         [Symbol(id)]: Buffer(12) [Uint8Array] [
    >            98,  34, 70, 144, 52,
    >           178, 255, 10, 133, 63,
    >           123, 120
    >         ]
    >       },
    >       reason: undefined,
    >       [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    >     }   },   _message: 'user validation failed' } [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

My user schema is as follow :

```js
    import mongoose from 'mongoose';
    import uniqueValidator from 'mongoose-unique-validator';
    import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
    
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    
    const UserSchema = new Schema({
      email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
      },
      firstname:{
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
      },
      lastname:{
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
      },
      
      password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        select: false
      }
    }, { timestamps: true });
    
    
    UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
      const user = this;
      // only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
      if (!user.isModified("password")) return next();
      // generate a salt
      bcrypt.genSalt((err, salt) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        // hash the password using our new salt
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
          if (err) return next(err);
          // override the cleartext password with the hashed one
          user.password = hash;
          next();
        });
      });
    });
    
    UserSchema.methods.isValidPassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
      const user = this;
      bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
          if (err) return cb(err);
          cb(null, isMatch);
      });
    };
    
    UserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);
    
    const UserModel = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
    
    
    export default UserModel;
```

Why mongoose is trying to create a new object ? Thanks for help

**UPDATE**

The issue seems to come from the module mongoose-unique-validator 3.0.0, when I comment the UserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator); it works

Answer (score 1):

It's because `.save()` is asynchronous, so you have to wait for it's response. Currently, your code will not wait for the response, and it will return 200 response message before the response from `.save()` is returned. You should add `await`:

```js
await user.save();
```

Comment: thank you the error is catched, however the issue still persist, UniqueValidator seems to be buggy. I have updated my code to be much easier to reproduce.